# i learned javascript and i am working on react but i didn't understand CSS. what i do?

Tags: javascript, css

I am learning react now and I spent my enough time on javascript. I tried to learn CSS but i couldn't confidient on this. I still learn CSS but it is so hard for me. I learned CSS for 4 months. please suggest me what i do?

Comment: *suggest me what i do* - learn CSS until you understand it - there's no "fix" for this other than you

Comment: You can follow the CSS Tutorial on https://www.w3schools.com/css/ for free...

Comment: have you looked into any "UI libraries" ... I too suck at CSS (particularly with colours - my attempts at design ended up looking like a slow 5 year olds finger painting) - I just use a UI library (don't ask which, I don't do reactjs)

Comment: Try freecodecamp to supplement your learning

Comment: Sorry @JaromandaX but there(s always something new to learn if you want to code.... I edited my comment but you're right : "learn CSS until you understand it" is a good answer.

Everything you learn is a plus!

Comment: As @JaromandaX mentioned, you can use UI libraries until you get more comfortable with CSS. I recommend DaisyUI (https://daisyui.com). It is built on top of TailwindCSS but does not require much Tailwind (or CSS for that matter) knowledge to get started.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

try tailwind CSS it will be good for you at least for now. don't stop yourself from learning other things just because of CSS. you'll see afterward that CSS doesn't really matters you just need the basic concepts of it. that's all. my advice is to forget about CSS for now. try tailwind CSS. as it is simple and saves more time.

Comment: `forget about CSS for now. try tailwind CSS` don't you have to understand CSS to use tailwind CSS? Seems like conflicting advice :p